# Database cache invalidation strategy and timing

Tags: sql, asp.net, caching

If you use the following strategy:

- An application level cache (like System.Web.Caching.Cache) to store SQL queries.
- Each cache entry is stored with a CacheDependancy tied to the primary keys of the rows returned.
- A database listener which listens for changes and invalidates the cache for a specific query when the rows it is dependant on changes.

This works quite well but the cache obviously isn't invalidated immediatly which has been problematic in a few cases.

One example is when the user adds a product to the shopping cart. The user will be taken to a new page which shows the contents of the cart. In this case, the cache isn't invalidated in time and the newly added item won't be present. If you reload the page, the listener has had time to run and the item is now there.

I'm struggling to find a solution to this which is generic. Is this a drawback with cache invalidation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution to all caching scenarios is unlikely, you'd probably be better tailoring your solution to your application using common methods such as Session / HttpContext depending on the duration you require objects to be cached for.

Things like cart items can be placed into session, items to be cached just for request duration could use HttpContext.Current.Items etc. Its more common that CacheDependency is used for more static items that change infrequently, and thus the delay would not matter.